# Sending an e-mail through Python

Tags: python, email, ssl, mime, smtplib

I've tried the code below to send a csv file to an e-mail address but for some reason the console shows the script running and it doesn't seem to end/execute. The script works fine without the csv attachment so I'm wondering if it has something to do with the code pertaining to the attachment.

Can someone please help? :(

```
import email, smtplib, ssl

from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

port = 465  # For SSL
subject = ""
body = ""
sender_email = ""
receiver_email = ""
password = ""

# Create a multipart message and set headers
message = MIMEMultipart()
message["From"] = sender_email
message["Subject"] = subject
message["Bcc"] = receiver_email  # Recommended for mass emails

# Add body to email
message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

filename = "EarningsReleaseData.csv"  # In same directory as script

# Open file in binary mode
with open(filename, "rb") as attachment:
    # Add file as application/octet-stream
    # Email client can usually download this automatically as attachment
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attachment.read())

# Encode file in ASCII characters to send by email    
encoders.encode_base64(part)

# Add header as key/value pair to attachment part
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = filename)

# Add attachment to message and convert message to string
message.attach(part)
text = message.as_string()

# Log in to server using secure context and send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

Comment: enclosing the code inside `try...except` may help you identify what exactly is happening.

Comment: how big is EarningsReleaseData.csv?